# javascript serialization without colomn name

Tags: javascript, asp.net, serialization, google-maps-api-3

Hi I want to retrieve latitude and longitude from database and saving it into hidden field.

Table dt retrieved from database

```
latitude        longitude   
19.2094000000   73.0939000000
19.2244070000   73.1545760000
19.1659242536   82.2436523438
18.3336694458   80.4309082031
```

I am using javascript serializer to save it in the hidden field

```
        JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        var Result = (from c in dt.AsEnumerable()
                      select new
                      {
                          Latitude = c.Field<Decimal>("Latitude"),
                          Longitude = c.Field<Decimal>("Longitude")
                      }).ToList();

        hdnControl.Value = oSerializer.Serialize(Result);
```

this results into

```
[
  {"Latitude":19.2094000000,"Longitude":73.0939000000},
  {"Latitude":19.2244070000,"Longitude":73.1545760000},
  {"Latitude":19.1659242536,"Longitude":82.2436523438},
  {"Latitude":18.3336694458,"Longitude":80.4309082031}
]
```

but I do not want column name in result data as I need to further process it and extract lat and long from it.

How can I save in hidden field without column name, so data would look like this?

```
[
  {19.2094000000,73.0939000000},
  {19.2244070000,73.1545760000},
  {19.1659242536,82.2436523438},
  {18.3336694458,80.4309082031}
]
```

Comment: Your target is not valid javascript, perhaps the θ, λ values should be in arrays rather than objects.

Comment: woww, thanx a lot ,this gives me new approach and in javascript array is accessible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would create a new array and add the formatted content in it:

```
var oldArr = [
  {"Latitude":19.2094000000,"Longitude":73.0939000000},
  {"Latitude":19.2244070000,"Longitude":73.1545760000},
  {"Latitude":19.1659242536,"Longitude":82.2436523438},
  {"Latitude":18.3336694458,"Longitude":80.4309082031}
];

var newArr = [];

for (i = 0; i < oldArr.length; i++) { 
    newArr.push({oldArr[i].Latitude, oldArr[i].Longitude});
}
```

"oldArr" is your array you've received from the database while "newArr" is a new created array.

Than you loop through all items of the old array and add only the value (without the key) of your old array's item.

at the end "newArr" contains exactly what you asked for.

Comment: Simpler is `oldArr.map(function(obj){return [obj.Latitute,obj.Longitude]})` or using an arrow function: `oldArr.map(obj=>[obj.Latitute,obj.Longitude])`. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Pls try this...

```
 string json = DataTableToJSON(dt_main); 
 jsonnew = @"{""Data"":" + json + "}";


private static string DataTableToJSON(DataTable table)
{

    List<string[]> result = table.Rows
 .Cast<DataRow>()
 .Select(row => row.ItemArray
     .Select(x => x.ToString())
     .ToArray())
 .ToList();

    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    return serializer.Serialize(result);

    //--------------another method------------
    //ArrayList arr = new ArrayList(); 
    //List<ArrayList> list = new List<ArrayList>();

    //foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    //{ 
    //    arr = new ArrayList();
    //    foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
    //    { 
    //       arr.Insert(col.Ordinal, row[col]);
    //    }

    //     list.Add(arr); 
    //} 

   // JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
   // return serializer.Serialize(list);


}
```